# Error when using jQuery Ajax POST (json) with php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

On page load I use this code to display data from database:

```
<script>

$(function feed(){

  var page = 1;
  var type = '<?php echo $filter ;?>';

  var theData = {};
  theData['page'] = 'profile';
  theData['type'] = type;
  theData['username'] = '<?php echo $user_data->username; ?>';
  theData['get_activities'] = 'true';

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "data.php",
      data: theData,
      dataType:'json',
      success: function(data){
          $("#activities").html(data.activity_feed);
          if(page < data.total_pages){
              $("#activities").after('<div id="loader"><button id="load_more_activities">Load more</button></div>');
          }
      }
  });
  $("#activity_container").on("click", "#load_more_activities", function(){
      var next = page+=1;
      var type = '<?php echo $filter ;?>';

      var theData = {};
      theData['page'] = 'profile';
      theData['type'] = type;
      theData['username'] = '<?php echo $user_data->username; ?>';
      theData['get_activities'] = 'true';
      theData['page_num'] = next;

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "data.php",
          data: theData,
          dataType: "json",

          success: function(data){
              $("#activities").append(data.activity_feed);
              if(next == data.total_pages){
                  $("#loader").html("No more data");
              } else {
                  $("#loader").html('<div id="loader"><button id="load_more_activities">Load more</button></div>');
              }
          },
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

Everything work fine, but if I refresh page more than 5 or 6 times or if load_more_activities function is called more than 5 or 6 times...then post is not executed and I don't get any data displayed...

Is something wrong with this code or there are maybe some restrictions from my host provider?

When post is executed:

[image]
[image]
[image]

When post is not executed:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This seems to be some kind of restriction or protection on your host provider. The failure requests are taking about 30 seconds to answer, which is a common timeout threshold. Did you checked if this also happens in other environment (like localhost)?

Comment: Not yet..I will install xampp and try..

Comment: I don't know why I haven't  already tried this yet :) Most of time I only work online live...so thank you to remind me to localhost..So in the end, It is kind of restriction with my host provider. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

My host provider has a protection from several sending ajax data with variables named "username" or "password". So when this happens, server detect some kind »brute-force« and then  drop-all-packets.